# Problems transferring database from .bak to new db

Tags: sql

I am trying to copy the database from a website to my local machine using a backup file `.bak`. Both databases are SQL Server 2012 Express. I need those data to test some reporting I am coding on my machine.

I have downloaded the `.bak` file from the hosting machine and used the following query to get the logical names:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY
FROM DISK = 'E:\Bkupdb61_01102013.bak'
```

I got the logical names:

[image]

Then I have created a new dummy database `DaSitoData2` to host the data and I have used the following query, from the `master` database, to restore the database from the `.bak` file:

```
RESTORE DATABASE DaSitoData2
FROM DISK = 'E:\Bkupdb61_01102013.bak'
WITH MOVE 'db486937961.mdf' TO 'C:\Users\Pink\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SSDT\DaSitoData2.mdf',
MOVE 'db486937961_log.ldf' TO 'C:\Users\Pink\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SSDT\DaSitoData2.ldf'
,REPLACE
```

I keep getting an error saying:

> Message 3234, level 16, state 2, row 5
>   The logical file 'db486937961.mdf' is not part of the database 'DaSitoData2'. To obtain the name list  of the logical files, use RESTORE FILELISTONLY.
>   Message 3013, level 16, state 1, row 5

I also tried to remove the `REPLACE` with a `GO`, but I get the same error.

Any help will be appreciated, I am stuck! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your screenshot... There's a column called **LogicalName**!

```
...
  MOVE 'Stadler_base' TO 'C:\Users\Pink\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\SSDT\DaSitoData2.mdf'
...
```

Comment: Got it! Was a long day.